# Why .htaccess does not support in Windows?

Tags: .htaccess

Good evening to all my beloved friends and respected participants!

I had face this problem that windows does not support .htaccess file .May I know why Window does not support this file extension?

Comment: Apache on Windows certainly does support .htaccess. However, on all platforms, the server or VirtualHost config must have [the appropriate `AllowOverride` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) or the .htaccess to be parsed.

Comment: Because it's not a file extension. It's the full name.

Comment: Thank you sir for your swift response! Can you depict me about the .htaccess .We know that if we save a file namely index.php so here .php is a file extension.So why not .htaccess is a file extension?

Comment: @AsrafulHaque On linux, when files start with `.` it makes the file hidden by default. This is what Apache has just chosen. Linux doesn't really care about file extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows can't use files without name, because the dot in the name means htaccess is an extension for it. Unfortunately it's not the case. .htaccess is the full name of the file. If you want to rename a txt file to .htaccess, you can use windows command line :

```
rename "file.txt" ".htaccess"
```

Comment: Why do we need this type of full name of the file?